# X2 capacitor. Test if failed open

Tags: capacitor, test, fault

I am looking at a small board in a paper shredder (it does not work). If I apply AC power and measure AC voltage across the X2 capacitor (I think it acts as a voltage dropper for the low voltage circuit), I read 240 V (line voltage). My conclusion is that the capacitor has failed open.

Is that the correct conclusion, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a reasonable chance the surge killed the zener, and it's gone short.

Your measurement of 0.9V across the series resistor (perhaps 50 or 100 ohms?) indicates that current is flowing (assuming the resistor is okay). That would not happen with an open capacitor and your measurement of 0V at the zener is therefore quite suspicious.

Comment: If your multimeter has a diode-test function @Denis, test the zener (circuit unpowered.) Positive to anode, it should measure ~0.7v like a normal diode. Reverse the leads and it should measure open, because most meters cannot supply enough voltage. The lower any reading in the reverse direction, the more likely it is shorted. If short, they typically fail < 0.2v in both directions.

Comment: Good tip for testing ^^^

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will check the zener again tonight

Comment: measuring the zener in both directions (multi-meter in diode mode) produces 0v both directions.

Comment: Probably dead then. If you pull it from the circuit and it still does that, definitely dead as a doornail.

Answer (score 1):

Since the capacitor will be in series with a resistor and then a rectifier bridge supplying a zener and the rest of the circuit, you are most likely  right.

The other option would be that the circuit itself is shorted, but in this case the current through the cap would drop some voltage in the series resistor (unless there is none, but that would be surprising).

You can clear doubt by measuring voltage across the rectifier bridge, zener, and series resistor. If the resistor reads 0V then there is no current, thus there is an open circuit, either inside the cap, or a cracked solder joint perhaps.

You can measure the capacitance if your multimeter has a cap-meter mode, of course you must unplug the device first. Usually, measuring components in-circuit isn't reliable, but in this case when the device is unplugged then the cap should actually be out of the circuit, since one of its pins is connected to the plug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Added more confidence.
Indeed. I measure 0 across the zenner and the two diodes (instead of the bridge rectifier) are not powered either. I do measure 0.9v AC across the series resistor though, but that does not seem significant.

Comment: I think we had a power surge. Quite some appliances in the house had their fuses popped. In this particular case, the fuse is also protecting a motor, so it is an extra slow one, so it did not blow, but over voltage most likely killed the cap.

Comment: 0 ohm across the zener is suspicious. Set multimeter to diode mode, and measure, let it connected for a while. Normally you would see a slowly rising voltage as the multimeter's tiny test current charges the power supply smoothing cap. If the voltage stays firmly at zero then Sphero is right and the zener is melted short.